# How can I deploy Vite app that uses MERN stact to Render.com?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vite

I have been trying to get my MERN app to run on Render, but I cannot get it to work.

```
root
        backend
            server.js
            controllers
            middleware
            models
            routes
            package.json
       public
       src
       package.json
```

I dont know if I structured it incorrectly. Here is the package.json in "backend"

```
{
  "name": "supportsys",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"vite\" \"npm run server\"",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@import-meta-env/unplugin": "^0.4.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

This is the package.json in my root folder

```
{
  "name": "supportsys",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"vite\" \"npm run server\"",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "start": "node backend/server.js",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@import-meta-env/unplugin": "^0.4.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "main": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

My server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();
const colors = require("colors");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
var cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;
const errorHandler = require("./middleware/errorMiddleware");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

connectDB();


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Set build folder as static
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../build")));


  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../index.html"));
  });
} else {
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Welcome to the API" });
  });
}


app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/userRoutes"));
app.use("/api/tickets", require("./routes/ticketRoutes"));
app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

I would appreciate if someone could point me towards a direction. I cannot possibly manage to host my backend as webservice, static site runs fine but backend is not there.

I deployed my backend to render and when I deploy my backend i get this error on console "Loading failed for the module with source “https://sys-ctzx.onrender.com/src/main.jsx”."